# Restforce get Sales Stages & Types

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

Does anyone know how to query the Salesforce API to get both stages & their associated types?

Specifically, I want to get the stage information as they are displayed on this page:

[image: Stages]

Specifically, the "Stage Name" and the "Type" as shown in the table.

Anyone know of an API endpoint to do that (or could point me to relevant documentation).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `OpportunityStage` object to describe the fields.

[image: Opprtunity Stages]

Also, navigate to Rest Explorer in workbench and perform this:

[image: Opportunity stage describe]

Comment: where `isClosed = true and isWon = false` => `Closed/Lost`; `isClosed = true and isWon = false` => `Closed/Won`